# Hide Column from .aspx Page Which is coming from SQL Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I Have Wrote SQL Stored Procedure 
Select Code [Code]
From ----
Where ---

now for some condition i want that code column but for some i didnt want that.How i can achieve this ?

Code :-

```
DataTable dtOutput= /Some function which return Datatable (accpet parameters as well for selection)

Table tOutput = / Some Function Which Converts Datatable to Table (For displaying it in HTML)

if (sTicketStatus == "0")
{
// Normal Statement which select all column coming from sql stored procedure
}
else
{
 foreach (TableRow trOutput in tOutput.Rows)
 {
 // What to write Here ?
 }
}
Page.Controls.Add(tOutput);
```

Comment: You could vary the select statement such that it only selects the columns you want... or remove the columns from the datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dtOutput.Columns.Remove(dtOutput.Columns["ColumnName"]);
```

Please try this code , this is for deleting a column.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
DataTable.DefaultView.ToTable(false, string_array_of_desire_columns[])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use View to select the specific columns...

```
dt.DefaultView.ToTable(false, "Column1", "Column2");
```

If you want distinct recod,send first parameter as True...
Please refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wec2b2e6.aspx